# How to avoid graph union name clash in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I am trying to merge six graphs into a single graph, using the `graph.union` function in igraph.

Each graph is directed, named, and bipartite. Each graph has the following vertex and edge attributes:

`name (v/c), type (v/c), label (v/c), id (v/c), edgeType (e/c), timestamp (e/c)`

However, when I merge the six graphs using `graph.union', it creates the following vertex and edge attributes:

`attr: type_1 (v/c), type_2 (v/c), type_3 (v/c), type_4 (v/c), type_5 (v/c), type_6 (v/c), label_1 (v/c), label_2 (v/c),
| label_3 (v/c), label_4 (v/c), label_5 (v/c), label_6 (v/c), id_1 (v/c), id_2 (v/c), id_3 (v/c), id_4 (v/c), id_5 (v/c),
| id_6 (v/c), name (v/c), edgeType_1 (e/c), edgeType_2 (e/c), edgeType_3 (e/c), edgeType_4 (e/c), edgeType_5 (e/c),
| edgeType_6 (e/c), timestamp_1 (e/c), timestamp_2 (e/c), timestamp_3 (e/c), timestamp_4 (e/c), timestamp_5 (e/c),
| timestamp_6 (e/c)`

How do I ensure that the final graph object does not generate all these additional attributes?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011479/how-to-restore-attribute-after-union-n-igraphs). I have added one new attribute to each igraph object only. Then graphs were unioned with the `union()` function and original values of attribute were restored.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible using `graph.union` (from the documentation: "union keeps the attributes of all graphs. All graph, vertex and edge attributes are copied to the result. If an attribute is present in multiple graphs and would result a name clash, then this attribute is renamed by adding suffixes: _1, _2, etc.").

As a workaround you could extract the nodes and edges from your six graphs using `as_data_frame(graph, what = "both")`, merge/bind the data frames accordingly and then convert back using `graph_from_data_frame`. Not sure whether that's more work than deleting the extra graph attributes.

Comment: Late reply, but I came across this problem again, and I can confirm your solution works. Thanks.