# How to restore attribute after union n igraphs?

Tags: r, for-loop, attributes, igraph, lapply

let's say I have `n` igraphs objects `g1`, `g2`,.., `gn`. They are undirected and weighted graphs, i.e. new weight's attribute should be added. I'd like to union `n` graphs into the weighted graph `g`.

It is known from the documentation (see `?graph.union`) if the `n` graphs have the `weight` attribute, it is renamed by adding a `_1` and `_2` (and `_3`, etc.) suffix, i.e. `weight_1`, `weight_2`,..., `weight_n`.

I have seen the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896087/union-of-igraph-objects-loses-attributes) and wrote the code for `n=3` graphs (see below).

**Edited:**

```
library(igraph)

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) # delete all objects

g1 <- graph_from_literal(A1-B1-C1)
g2 <- graph_from_literal(A2-B2-C2)
g3 <- graph_from_literal(A3-B3-C3)

E(g1)$weight <- c(1, 2)
E(g2)$weight <- c(3, 4)
E(g3)$weight <- c(5, 6)


g        <- union(g1, g2, g3)

new_attr <- as.list(list.edge.attributes(g))
k        <- length(new_attr) # number of new attributes

value_new_attr <- lapply(list.edge.attributes(g), 
                         function(x) get.edge.attribute(g,x))

df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:k) {df <- rbind(df, value_new_attr[[i]])}
E(g)$weight <- colSums(df, na.rm=TRUE)

g <- delete_edge_attr(g, "weight_1") # 1
g <- delete_edge_attr(g, "weight_2") # 2
g <- delete_edge_attr(g, "weight_3") # 3
```

**Question.** How to rewrite the last tree commands with the `lapply()` function?

**My attempt does not work:**

```
g <- lapply(value_new_attr, function(x) {g <- delete_edge_attr(g, x)})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution with `for-loop`

```
# delete edge attributes with suffix
for (i in 1:k) {g <- delete_edge_attr(g, new_attr[i])}
```